# Get cart item by using cart item id

Tags: cart, magento-1.8

I am updating multiple cart items at a glance. And i have updated cart item id's with me. Now i want to get CART item data by its id.

Can you plese help me on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be done with the `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` class. If you're updating several items it might be better to use it's collection tho.

```
$the_item_ids = array(2,5,6,8);

$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()
   ->addFieldToFilter('item_id', array('in' => $the_item_ids));

foreach($collection as $item)
{
  var_dump($item->getData());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can i do like this: $cartItem = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemById($item['itemId']);

Comment: @SelectSmile I'm not sure if that method exists but if so, yes

Comment: AFAIK `getItemById()` is defined in `Varien_Data_Collection` and should be available in all collections.

Answer (score 1):

we can load quote item object by item_id directly.

```
$itemObject = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($itemId);
```

This is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this because of `_assignOptions` and `_assignProducts` in `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection:`

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_item_collection')
     ->setQuote($quote) // this is the model not an id.
     ->addFieldToFilter('item_id', array('in' => $quoteItemIds));
```

If no quote is set, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

To be straightforward this is what you need to load a quote(cart) item by its id

```
$_quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItemId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('item_id');
$_quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')
              ->setQuote($_quote)
              ->load($cartItemId);
```