# Magento Sales quote collection error

Tags: collection, sales, quote

I am getting sales quote collection with [this reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12183/get-cart-item-by-using-cart-item-id),,but it throws below error.

**MyCode**

```
Mage::log($item_ids);
$collection=Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('item_id',array('in'=>$item_ids));
foreach($collection as $item)
    {
        Mage::log($item);
    }
```

**Log**

```
2014-12-10T13:13:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => 3030
    [1] => 3032
    [2] => 3056
    [3] => 3057
    [4] => 3070
)
```

**Error**    showing on frontend white screen with this message.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getStoreId() on a non-object in /var/www/beta/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Item/Collection.php on line 67
```

What is wrong in my code? .

Comment: You are getting this error because you have the quote item isolated. It does not have a quote associated to it. This may work in some cases but in others (like yours) it doesn't. Can you post the code you are using on frontend?

Comment: @Marius Which code you are asking?

Comment: The error appears when you run the code you posted in the question? Or is there something else?

Comment: @Marius I tried in Collection.php's `getStoredId() Mage::log($this->_quote);` this returns empty, so this error occurs.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently this is a bug.
You cannot use the `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection` without linking it to a quote.
Because of this:
When the collection is loaded the method `_assignProducts` from the same class is called.
this method dispatches an event

```
    Mage::dispatchEvent('prepare_catalog_product_collection_prices', array(
        'collection'            => $productCollection,
        'store_id'              => $this->getStoreId(),
    ));
```

This event requires a store id that is retrieved like this:

```
public function getStoreId()
{
    return (int)$this->_quote->getStoreId();
}
```

When using the collection directly the `_quote` member is empty.